# Як правильно: Middle-розробник чи Middle розробник? + Java-розробник чи Java розробник?

Tags: пунктуація, разом-дефіс-окремо

Вітаю!

Товариство, маю два питання.

1/ Middle-розробник чи Middle розробник? Де Middle -- рівень розробника (градація в компанії: Junior, Middle, Senior).

2/ Мідлрозробник чи мідл-розробник? За Правописом 2019 (§ 35 5.2) разом пишемо слова з першими регулярно вживаними іншомовними компонентами. Але чи "мідл" є регулярно вживаним компонентом?

3/ Java-розробник чи Java розробник? Java -- назва технології, спеціалізація (мова програмування та платформа).

Буду вдячна за поради та обґрунтування.

Comment: Вітаємо на цьому сайті. Будь ласка, публікуйте різні запитання окремо один від одного. Звісно, окрім випадку, коли ви самі вважаєте, що ці три запитання по своїй суті є одне й те саме (мені здається, що №1 та №3 однакові, а №2 суттєво відрізняється від них).

Comment: > маю два питання. [задає три питання] :)